# Force all requests to use https:// and prepend www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have spent countless hours trying to solve this problem and it's doing my head in. I'm sure that it is very simple but none of the answers I have found either on stackoverflow.com or other sites work for me.

I am using an SSL certificate that is only valid for www.example.com and for a myriad of silly corporate reasons I am stuck with only this certificate.

I would like to force all requests to use SSL and prepend www. to the domain. All of the following domains rewrite correctly:

```
example.com/
http://example.com/
http://www.example.com/
https://www.example.com/
```

The domain that is not rewritten and is the one problem I cannot find the answer to anywhere is

```
https://example.com
```

It simply spits out the usual "Certificate Is Not Valid" warning.

I have the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I really hope that somebody has a solution for me because I cannot find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=302,L]
```

It will check to see if it has `www` in the url, if it doesn't then it will add it. Then it will check and see if it is `https` and if it isn't then it will add it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Behaviour now exactly what I need.